# is storing frequently used data in json in mysql worth it?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

in vue.js app the main focus is working with prospects.  prospects have many things like contacts, listings, and half a dozen other objects/tables.

they also have interactions, which could have 30 or more per prospect, while most things like emails or phones would have 1-3 results.  I load 50 prospects at a time in to the front end

I'm trying to decide if loading it all into the front end to work 50 prospects at a time is a good idea, or if i should have a json column with interactions as part of the prospects table that i would update each time an interaction is saved, with minimal info like date, type, subject...

it seems like an extra step (and duplicate data, how important is that?) to update the json column with each interaction, but also seems like it would save looking up and loading data all the time

I'm not a programmer, but have been teaching myself how to do something i need done for my business with tutorials and youtube, any opinions from those who deal with this professionally would be appreciated

also, if anyone wants to tell me how to ask this question in a better formatted way, I'm open ears

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if you have 1000 data, but you are sending only 50 of them, and your user do a filter by price. Will you display only the filtered data from 50 or 1000 of them?

That depends on whether you want to expose all 1000 data to the front end. It's a choice between that, and calling your server api everytime.

If you are calling the server, consider using a cache like Redis to store your results .

Pseudo code.

```
Request Received
    Check Redis Cache - Redis.get('key')
        If key exist - return cache.
        Else - 
            check mysql for latest results.
            Redis.set('key', latest results);


CreateRequest Received
     - Write to mysql
     - Redis.delete('key')  // next request to view will create new cache with fresh data.
```

Your key can be anything like, e.g your url ('/my/url')

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis

Comment: i have to be honest, I don't know what that is, i'll go down the rabbit hole though...

Comment: redis is very very commonly used as a data cache layer, so you don't need to repeatedly query your mysql for same results.

Comment: thank you for your response, it would be nice to expose 1000 to the front end for the purpose of filtering, but not that common of a need, users need to work the prospects from newest to oldest, so logically they would be working 50 at a time, if they wanted to find only those with status x, wouldn't it just be easier to hit the api and load 50 that are status x,y or z?

Comment: yes u r right. My understanding of your question is whether to load 50 or 1000 to be interact-able.

Comment: my bad, this is my first post here, and I'm probably not asking questions totally right, do you have an opinion about a separate json column in the prospects table to summarize interactions v. an InteractionsResource::collection for interactions.  that collection would be far larger than the whole prospects resource in most cases

Comment: I believe you are only showing limited columns in the table e.g. Name, Mobile, Email, and for individual records, it consist of MANY MANY data. In most case, in our filter table, we only request Name, Mobile, Email from the database.

Comment: its actually set up as a prospect can have many contacts and a contact can have many phone numbers or emails, in which many really only is an array of a few, but when you get to interactions, it could be a lot bigger, and I don't really need to see all the interactions for an overview, but i do want to know how many, most recent and of which type

Comment: i'm sorry, it seems like i'm trying to have a conversation in the comments section, which is not cool, again, my first time here, i do appreciate the feedback and help